# Why 'Results Not Found' while passing numbers through HTML/PHP form?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

This code works when the html form select element 'year' is not added, or only passing non-number values. I've also tried having the numbers in quotes and without quotes.

The year 2017 works and passes the value for some reason, but 2018 and some other numbers do not work.

I coded a work around passing words, and then assigning number values afterwards using php switch. Hoping there is something simple I am missing, getting coding eyes staring at the same code for too long.

This code is the current work around, that does work:

```
<?php

// MSIADA 

 global $post;
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category_name' => 'msiada-rewards', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc');
 $posts = get_posts($args);

?>

<h3><center>[Select Auction House | Coupons REDEEMED]</center></h3>

<form action="" method="get">

<!--  NO IDEA WHY 2017 works and 2018 gets 'No Results Found' whaaa ? ? 

 <select name="year">   
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
 </select> -->

 <select name="year">   
    <option value="blue">2018</option>
    <option value="yellow">2017</option>
 </select>

<select name="vendor_select" id="page_id">
                <option value="-" disabled selected>Please Select...</option>
                <option value="all_auctions">ALL AUCTIONS</option>

<?php

 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <option value="<? echo $post->post_name; ?>|<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

 </select>



 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="um_button" value="SUBMIT" />

 </form>



<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

$vendor_select = $_REQUEST['vendor_select'];
$yearColor = $_REQUEST['year'];


switch ($yearColor) {

    case 'yellow';

        $year = 2017;

    break;

    case 'blue';

        $year = 2018;

    break;

}

switch ($vendor_select) {

    case '';

        echo "<br><h2>All Auctions | " . $year . "</h2>";
        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=49] ' );

    break;

    case 'all_auctions';

        echo "<br><h2>All Auctions | " . $year . "</h2>";
        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=49 var1=' . $year . '] ' );

    break;

    default; 


            $vendor_select_explode = explode('|', $vendor_select);
            $vendor_name = $vendor_select_explode[0];
            $vendor_title = $vendor_select_explode[1];

    echo "<br><h2>" . $vendor_title . " | " . $year . "</h2>";      

        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=40 var1=' . $vendor_name . ' var2=' 
    . $year . '] ' );
    } 
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the code below with the first php switch taken out, and the original select 'year' activated. I just tested this code, and now 2017 shows 'no results', but 2018 now does appear to be working.

Here are the string results of the broken code:

```
http://pearnow.com/test3/?year=2017&vendor_select=all_auctions&submit=SUBMIT
http://pearnow.com/test3/?year=2018&vendor_select=all_auctions&submit=SUBMIT
```

Here is the non-working code:

```
<?php

// MSIADA - broken code no results

 global $post;
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category_name' => 'msiada-rewards', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc');
 $posts = get_posts($args);

?>

<h3><center>[Select Auction House | Coupons REDEEMED]</center></h3>

<form action="" method="get">

<!--  NO IDEA WHY 2017 works and 2018 gets 'No Results Found' whaaa ? ? -->
<!-- Update: Now 2017 doesn't work, but 2018 does. Switched position of select elements, but no difference -->

 <select name="year">   
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
 </select>

<select name="vendor_select" id="page_id">
                <option value="-" disabled selected>Please Select...</option>
                <option value="all_auctions">ALL AUCTIONS</option>

<?php

 foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <option value="<? echo $post->post_name; ?>|<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

 <?php endforeach; ?>

 </select>



 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="um_button" value="SUBMIT" />

 </form>



<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

$vendor_select = $_REQUEST['vendor_select'];
$year = $_REQUEST['year'];


switch ($vendor_select) {

    case '';

        echo "<br><h2>All Auctions | " . $year . "</h2>";
        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=49] ' );

    break;

    case 'all_auctions';

        echo "<br><h2>All Auctions | " . $year . "</h2>";
        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=49 var1=' . $year . '] ' );

    break;

    default; 


            $vendor_select_explode = explode('|', $vendor_select);
            $vendor_name = $vendor_select_explode[0];
            $vendor_title = $vendor_select_explode[1];

    echo "<br><h2>" . $vendor_title . " | " . $year . "</h2>";      

        echo do_shortcode ( ' [wpdatatable id=40 var1=' . $vendor_name . ' var2=' . $year . '] ' );
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to include your code

Comment: When you're using the commented out `<select>`, are you modifying your `switch` statement to look for numbers and not strings?

Comment: Please post how your switch statement looks when you use the `<select>` that *doesn't work*. Your switch is likely taking an input of 0 and trying to find the closest match e.g. the first case.

Comment: There is no need for the php switch if passing the numbers. I am using the switch only to assign numbers to the words afterwards.

So, if you can imagine no switch, with the select activated. That is when no response occurs. I can paste in the code that shows the error. maybe this would be better?

Also, thanks for your quick replies guys, did not expect response so fast.

Comment: @JohnPedersen But if you only pass numbers, the `$year` variable doesn't get filled and that is what is used in your code at the bottom?

Comment: The $year variable seems to get filled fine with the first switch. It echos out correctly. Do I need to do something else when setting $year = $_REQUEST['year']; in the broken version of the code?